# How to script the rename of multiple files using the Mac command line

Tags: bash

I have a folder which has a bunch of screenshots. The filenames all start with `Screen` and end with `.png`, I want to rename the entire filenames as `1.png`, `2.png`, etc.. using terminal in Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
i=1; for f in Screen*.png; do mv "$f" "$i.png" ; i=$((i + 1)); done
```

or the same as a script

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
for f in Screen*.png
do
    mv "$f" "$i.png"
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using (perl) `rename` command:

```
rename 's/.*\.png/sprintf("file-%04d.png",$=++-59)/e' Screen*png
```

And for keepind chronologic order:

```
rename 's/.*\.png/sprintf("file-%04d.png",$=++-59)/e' $(/bin/ls -1tr Screen*png)
```

Explanation:

`rename` is a script installed in Un*x systems with the [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) base.

In perl, `$=` hold the current page length (default is 60). While nothing is printed. this variable is and integer variable that could be used for anything you want ;-)

Comment: This is a *trick*: `$=` hold *paper length* in lines. On my system, `perl -e 'print"$=\n";'` give `60`. Thats the reason of `-60` in my command line.

Comment: I think this could also work under MacOS. Feed-back welcome!!

Comment: it looks like a nice idea :) i'll do some tests!

Answer (score -1):

Go to your folder

```
TEMP=$(ls)
j=1
i=$(ls | wc -l)
for c in $TEMP; do mv $c $(i-j).png ; done;
```

Comment: Not working as a bash script. Could you recheck it, please.